# Proper Swing Design

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I've heard that putting the same-level component on top of another same-level component is bad practice.

I'm talking about JPanels in this case. I currently divide everything into separate JPanels where each has its own layout, and then I add them to the main content pane (JPanel). I feel like this way is much easier than having to configure a layout that will work for all my components that can be all over the place. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: I don't understand your first statement, but your second seems fine to me.  Better to isolate complex layouts within there own container - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Basically, is it wrong to have multiple JPanels over a parent JPanel? And even if it isn't wrong, is there a better solution that I could be using?

Comment: @Languages: no, it's not wrong to add multiple JPanels to a parent JPanel. We do it all the time. I'm still not sure what initiated this question or where exactly you're going with this. Please provide some background information.

Comment: If any one complains, I'd just show them [`TitledBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html). It's whole purpose is to separate distinct parts of complex ui forms into manageable chunks. Be careful though, there is always a point where to much information is a bad thing. That's where `JTabbedPanes` and `CardLayout` comes to play. But essentially, no, it's not a bad practice in general

Comment: No, your logic is way too good, this is what you call `Nested Layout` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having panels inside of panels.  However, if you are doing a lot of that, you may want to consider a layout manager (my favorite is [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)) that supports fairly complex arrangement of controls without using tons of nested panels.

At the end of the day, use a composition that makes it easier for you to maintain your code.  If you have groupings of controls that are independent of each other, then having them in separate panels is good design - it allows you to split that panel out (for testing, or even for creative windowing in the UI).  If the sets of controls are intrinsically tied to each other, consider a single panel with an advanced layout manager.

In some cases, you'll have a small amount of binding between two panels (classic example is one panel with a list and another panel with a detail view for the selected item in the list).  In this case, I generally use two separate panels, and two separate presentation models, then bind the current selected item in one model to the parent of the inspector panel.  But if you find that you are using values from multiple panels for things like validation, data storage, etc... then you may have things split into too many panels.

I've done a lot of this over the years, and the position I've settled on is to compose my UIs along logical lines of the underlying presentation models that back the views.  Very rarely do I let the layout of the UI drive how many panels I use, etc... - MigLayout (and I'm sure there are others) make even complex UI layouts fairly straightforward, and it's much better to design the classes for the view and model in a way that make the code easier to test and maintain.